# How to get JSON out of AFNetworing 2.0 GET Method

Tags: ios, arrays, json, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking to make a bunch of API calls at once to Instagram. I am using AFNetworking 2.0 AFHTTPSessionManager GET request.

I am using a for loop to create the URL which requires a location ID that I am searching. The for loop then makes in this case 3 separate API calls and stores each response in an array.

I then create a mutable array to store the objects in the array. I need to get the mutable array once it has all three objects in it. I have tried passing the data to another method, but then I get into the same problem - can't really use the array until the previous method is done running.

```
    -(void)sendGetRequestForLocationMedia:(NSMutableArray*)mutableArray{
   for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
      NSString *getLocationMediaString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"locations/%@/media/recent?client_id=%@", self.locationIDObjectArray[i], client_id];
       NSLog(@"getLocationMediaString %@", getLocationMediaString);

        [[LPAuthClient sharedClient]GET:getLocationMediaString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            {
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
                if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        _locationMediaArray = responseObject[@"data"];
                        if (!_locationMediaJSONArray) {
                            _locationMediaJSONArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        }

                        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in _locationMediaArray) {

                            [_locationMediaJSONArray addObject:dictionary];
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure %@", error);
        }];
   }

}
```